MAUI Picker inside CollectionView
I'm pretty new to MAUI development, so I do not get this running. I have a list of messages and each message has a status. I want to allow the user to change each data row's status. I am already using mvvm.
My XAML looks something like this:
<CollectionView VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Default"
            HorizontalOptions="Fill"
            VerticalOptions="Fill"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ListMessages}">

<CollectionView.Header>
    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*">
        <Label Text="Header"/>
        <Label Text="Status"/>
    </Grid>
</CollectionView.Header>

<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Message">
        <Frame>
            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*">
                <Label Text="{Binding Header}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <Picker Grid.Column="2"
                        x:Name="StatusPicker"
                        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding ????}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ????}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding ?????}"
                        />
            </Grid>
        </Frame>
    </DataTemplate>
</CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

And my ViewModel should look something like this:
public partial class ViewModel : BaseViewModel
{

public ViewModel() 
{
    ListMessageStatus = new ObservableCollection<MessageStatus>();
}

public ObservableCollection<MessageStatus> ListMessageStatus { get; set; }


}

My MessageStatus looks like this:
public class MessageStatus 
{
    public int Id { get; set; } = -1;
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}

What I want to achieve now is to have a Picker which shows MessageStatus.Name and if I select a different value as Message.Status, then I need a method to be called that receives the whole Message and the new Message.Status to send it to my backend and change those data. For some reason I am not able to select anything else inside the Picker as the message defined in the DataTemplate.

BTW, your ListMessageStatus property should be { get; }-only, not { get; set; }.

ItemsSource needs to be a relative binding to your base VM.  SelectedItem will be a binding to the status property of the individual message

@Jason ItemSource is now working, but I still have the problem that SelectedItem is not working. The Model returns int and my ItemSource is a Collection of MessageStatus. How do I manage that binding?

You may try including the MessageStatus collection into the Message model.
Let's say we have a ObservableCollection,
 public ObservableCollection<Message> ListMessages { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Message>();

And for the Message model, you may add the ListMessageStatus in it,
public class Message : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Header { get; set; }

    public MessageStatus selectedItem;
    public MessageStatus SelectedItem 
    {            
        get
        {
            return selectedItem;
        }                                  
        set
        {
            ////// each time you change the status, this setter method will be executed
            selectedItem = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedItem)));
        }            
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MessageStatus> ListMessageStatus { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MessageStatus>();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
}

To consume in XAML,
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Message">
        <Frame>
            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*">
                <Label Text="{Binding Header}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <Picker Grid.Column="2"
                    x:Name="StatusPicker"
                    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding ListMessageStatus}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"           
                />
            </Grid>
        </Frame>

So, when we change the picker, the Setter method of SelectedItem in Message model will also be changed.
